# MySQL collation query results

Tags: mysql, collation

does anyone has explaination why :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1 = 1 AND libelle COLLATE latin1_general_ci LIKE '%dég%'
```

returns 1 record (only the record with é) while

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1 = 1 AND libelle COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci LIKE '%dég%'
```

returns 4 record (of course including the one above) ?

According to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html) latin1_general_ci is "Multilingual (Western European) case insensitive" so should not it manage accents like latin1_swedish_ci ?

Thanks
Nicolas

Comment: There are many languages spoken in western Europe. I doubt they all share the same rules as Swedish.

Comment: show the results for both queries please

Comment: Please show the other values that matched differently for the different queries.

Comment: You should consider switching from `latin1` to `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Here are the 4 records :
dégradation
degradation
degradation
degradation

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're misunderstanding what collation is.

Collation is a set of rules used in natural language (Swedish, English, Russian, Japanese...) to determine the dictionary order of words. In relational databases, this is used to sort data (e.g. `ORDER BY` clauses) and to compare data (e.g. `WHERE` clauses or unique indexes). A couple of examples:

- If you need to order by country name in English you get this:

  1. Canada
  2. China
  3. Colombia

  However, in traditional Spanish `ch` used to be an independent letter so correct order was this:

  1. Canada
  2. Colombia
  3. China
- In Swedish, `å` is a separate letter so you can have a login name like `ångström` even if you already have `angström`. In other languages they'd be duplicates and would not be allowed.

Collation is **not** something you use to display emojis and other Unicode characters. That's just *encoding* (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16... whatever).